# How can I capture video and play it with C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture

I want to build application which needs to be able to capture video from a web camera using C#. The captured video should be compressed using some codec (nothing special, anything available that saves space) and written to a file while capturing. A live preview of capture is not necessary.

The first question is: Which API is suitable for this and what would you recommend (I have seen DirectShow, Windows Media Foundation wrapper, etc. I am not sure which is would be best for managed environment and C#)?

I also need a video player in [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) which will play captured video. This player must be able to play captured video from an arbitrary position, pause and start/stop video.

Putting it all together, video is captured from a webcam in the background and at the same time the player plays that video being captured, but it can be paused, re-winded, stopped - something like a modern DVR.

The second question: Is it possible to create such a player using WPF MediaElement? (Confusion is about the file which is at the same time filled from the capture and played in the player)

Comment: You need to make your question a lot more specific - break it into chunks that deal with specific problems you're having after attempting something.

Comment: I need a recommendation on which API (technology) to use for the capture, it is not question about problem it is about recommendation!

Comment: In that case, it's not suitable for StackOverflow I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice example of how to make all what you want: [WebCam](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library)

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) set of libraries to accept the videos frame by frame. I used the *private void videoSourcePlayer1_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image)* function to do this.

Comment: As they tagged WPF i assume they want to use it in WPF and aforge seems to only be winforms compatable

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [DirectShow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [VlcDotNet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/). It is very flexible and simple to use. It has a pretty active user base as well.

I've used it for displaying live video streams as well as recording to files.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend WPF's [ffmediaelement](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement). It's built on [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org). So what can FFmpeg, can also ffmediaelement. It can capture video from both the webcam and the capture card. Unlike DirectShow, it's very simple.

Here's how to set up a video source:

```
Media.Source = new Uri("device://dshow/?video=Osprey-460e Video Device 1C");
```

... and parameters for it in MediaOpening event:

```
Media.OnMediaOpening(s, e) =>
{
    e.Options.Input["framerate"] = "25";
    e.Options.Input["video_size"] = "768x576";
    e.Options.Input["pixel_format"] = "yuyv422";
};
```

Comment: The sentence starting with *"So what can FFmpeg"* is practically incomprehensible. Can you fix it?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*). Perhaps somebody else can untangle it? What should that sentence be?